# How to delete duplicates in vector (without sorting) C++

Tags: c++

I have a vector that the user inputs some strings. I want to keep the order that the user inputs but delete any duplicate words. The only thing I could find online is sort and unique but since I cannot sort the vector I am stuck. Thank you in advance for any help.

e.x. 
  input from user -> hello there dog cat hello cat book

vector should have -> hello there dog cat book

right now all I have is...

```
string s; 
vector <string> myVec; 

while (cin >> s){
 myVec.push_back(s); 
}

{code to sort vector}
```

Answer (score 10):

Alongside your `vector`, you can test whether the word is already in a [`std::set<std::string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert), ignoring it if so, otherwise inserting it in both containers:

```
while (cin >> s)
    if (mySet.insert(s).second) // newly inserted in set?
        myVec.push_back(s);
```